# How to estimate MOI for a complex cell type

Tags: cell-biology, virology, retrovirus

I am currently confused about the estimation of multiplicity of infection (MOI), here is an example in a [scientific article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0896627316304214?via%3Dihub)

in figure 3b, they tested the virus, and get estimated MOI based on this:

> To estimate the MOI, we isolated a total of 45 individual neurons from three animals injected with MAPseq virus into the right LC and sequenced the barcodes within each neuron. On average, infected LC neurons contained 1.2 ± 0.1 barcodes each, implying MOI of 0.43 (Figure 3B).

I am confused which equation they used for estimating?

Thanks in advance!